# Live location in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to get the coordinates of live location in flutter ? I want to get the live location coordinates. What could be done to get this ? I am imported the location package in flutter but I just want to get the coordinates of live location .

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to get a location plugin.
https://pub.dev/packages/location. Also I recommend that use Provider plugin and create model files. It will be more easier to manage.  In addition , you have to check permission status of your device . you will reach all of information what you want to learn through link

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 Location _location = Location();
 LocationData currentLocation;


@override
  void initState() {
    location = new Location();
    location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData cLoc) {
      currentLocation = cLoc;

      });

    super.initState();
  }


  @override


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
  child: Text(
      'Location: Lat${currentLocation.latitude}, Long: ${currentLocation.longitude}'),);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
Location location = new Location();

bool _serviceEnabled;
PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;
LocationData _locationData;

_serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
if (!_serviceEnabled) {
  _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
  if (!_serviceEnabled) {
    return;
  }
}

_permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
  _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
  if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    return;
  }
}

location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
  // Use current location
});
```

Comment: Actually I want to create the create the navigation between the live location and destination points. But navigation only take waypoints. So how to use live location in waypoints                           onPressed: () async {
                            var wayPoints = List<WayPoint>();
                            wayPoints.add(_origin);
                            wayPoints.add(_stop1);
                            await _directions.startNavigation(
                                wayPoints: wayPoints, )

Comment: where waypoints has been defined the following way-                                                               final _origin = WayPoint(
      name: "Way Point 1",
      latitude: 38.9111117447887,
      longitude: -77.04012393951416);
  final _stop1 = WayPoint(
      name: "Way Point 2",
      latitude: 38.91113678979344,
      longitude: -77.03847169876099);                                                                                       So how can I use taht live coordinates points in that?